# Regex to math authentication failures in /var/log/secure

Tags: regex, authentication, ssh, collectd

I'm trying to math strings in `/var/log/secure` with regex to get if there is a ssh authentication failure.

If there is an authentication failure it will look like this in the log file:

`Oct 31 07:52:41 logserver sshd[17041]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost`

I tried do something like this:

`"\\<sshd[^:]*: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; ./* \\>"`

But it dosen't not work. I'd appreciate if some could help me with regular expressions.

*This is on a CentOS 7 machine and the regex is for collectd's plugin `tail`.*

Comment: What is the result you are expecting? (eg. the line to output, etc.)

Comment: @l'L'l I'm tryging to math this: "pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure"

Comment: Why not just do `grep 'authentication failure' /var/log/secure`

Comment: @l'L'l I can't really do that because the regex is for statistic daemon "collectd" and it dont accpet commands just plain regular expressions like my example above.

Comment: If you are setting the regex in the configuration then you could probably do `Regex "authentication failure|failure|authentication"`

Comment: @l'L'l Oooh wow, that worked great. Didn't know it could be that simple! Thanks mate!

Comment: You might just want `authentication failure` by itself, as if there are any other log messages with `authentication` or `failure` (possibly unrelated to what you are targeting) they will show also). `sshd:auth[^:]*: authentication failure;` might actually be the most precise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **collectd** `.conf` you could likely use one of the following:

```
<Plugin "tail">
  <File "/var/log/secure">
    ...
    <Match>
```

Option 1:

```
    Regex "authentication failure"
```

Option 2:

```
    Regex "sshd:auth[^:]*: authentication failure;"
```

Option 3:

```
    Regex "authentication failure|authentication|failure"
```

Where option 1 and 2 should be the most precise for matching, and option 3 more generalized. Option 1 finds the exact phrase `authentication failure`, Option 2 finds the exact phrase along with (sshd:auth): preceding it, and Option 3 finds the exact phrase or "authentication" or "failure".

```
    </Match>
  </File>
</Plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks mate once again! I wen't with option 2. Works great!